# Set EndDate to value of EventDate with jQuery

Tags: jquery, column, date-time, datepicker

how can I set field EndDate automatically to value of field EventDate with jQuery after user choice EventDate from calendar?

I use code, but it doesn't work for me:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#EventDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date){
        var dates = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
$("#EndDate").val(dates);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#EventDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function () {
            var dt2 = $('#EndDate');
            var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            //add 0 days to selected date
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 0);
            var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            //minDate of dt2 datepicker = dt1 selected day
            dt2.datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            //sets dt2 maxDate to the last day of 30 days window
            dt2.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
            //first day which can be selected in dt2 is selected date in dt1
            dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            //same for dt1
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        }
    });
    $('#EndDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Sorry for stupid question but what I have to change insted  #EventDate and #EndDate? Field ID or FieldInternalName? With or within " " or  ' ' or "#"?

Comment: my html looks like this:

<input id="EventDate" type="text" />
<input id="EndDate" type="text" />

Comment: so id should be that of the <input> tag

Comment: Thank you, it works but only if I change date in a field EventDate, not from calendar beside this field od EventDate. Could you add some code to do this?